# Binding View to DataContext from another ViewModel Class

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel, datacontext

I am using the MVVM pattern and came across this problem.

I would like to create a SpecificProductViewModel object by passing the product for which I want the specific view by parameter from my ProductListViewModel class (which contains all the products) with the following function:

```
private void OnProductNav(tblMATProduct product)
    {
        if (product != null)
        {
            CurrentProduct = product;
            SpecificProductVM = new SpecificProductViewModel(product);
            CurrentProductViewModel = SpecificProductVM;
            SpecificProductVM.Product = product;
        }
    }
```

I would then need to assign the DataContext of my SpecificProductView to my SpecificProductViewModel in the code-behind like this:

```
DataContext = new SpecificProductViewModel();
```

The problem however, is that a new object of SpecificProductViewModel gets created by doing so and the DataContext is therefore not using the data (tblMATProduct product) passed by parameter when the object was created from the ProductListViewModel class.

Would there be a way to assign the DataContext directly from the ProductListViewModel class or to be able to get the tblMATProduct product from the code-behind or in the xaml?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:** I was thinking like Lennart by doing this:

```
DataContext = new ProductListViewModel();
```

The problem though is that the specificViewModel instance needs to be created right after the user clicks on a specific product.

Therefore, if we create a new instance of ProductListViewModel in the code-behind and assign it ProductListViewModel, the instance won't know on what the user clicked and won't call the function OnProductNav.

**Edit 2 :** Adding more precision.

```
class ProductListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

  private SpecificProductViewModel SpecificProductVM;

  public tblMATProduct CurrentProduct { set; get; }

  public ViewModelBase CurrentProductViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentProductViewModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _currentProductViewModel, value); }
    }

  public ProductListViewModel() {
    ProductNavCommand = new MyICommand<tblMATProduct>(OnProductNav);
  }

  private void OnProductNav(tblMATProduct product)
    {
        if (product != null)
        {
            SpecificProductVM = new SpecificProductViewModel(product);
            CurrentProductViewModel = SpecificProductVM;
        }

    }
}
```

In my ProductListView, I have a DataGrid with all my products where the user can select a row (specific product) by clicking on it.

```
<Datagrid>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProductNavCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my SpecificProductViewModel

```
class SpecificProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private tblMATProduct _product;


    public tblMATProduct Product
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _product, value); }
    }

    public SpecificProductViewModel()
    {

    }

    public SpecificProductViewModel(tblMATProduct product)
    {
        Product = product;
    }
}
```

And here is a few lines of code from SpecificProductView.xaml which will bind to SpecificProductViewModel.cs

```
<Grid Background="Red" Height="800" Width="1350" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product.FormatID}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product.SpecificProductVM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product.GradeID}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

**Edit 3: Adding another layer of precision**

To answer mm8's question, as I have just started working with WPF and MVVM, I have always assumed that if the `View's DataContext` is binded to the corresponding `ViewModel`, the instance of the `View` will be created automatically when a `ViewModel` instance is created via the xaml Datatemplate in `ProductListView.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type viewModels:SpecificProductViewModel}">
    <products:SpecificProductView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is where I would usually create my `DataContext`.

`SpecificProductView.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class SpecificProductView : UserControl
{
    public SpecificProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SpecificProductViewModel();
    }
}
```

**Edit 4: Explaining how the Data Template is handled**

Here is the ContentControl which launches the view of the SpecificProductView.  It uses

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentProductViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
```

It binds to this which determines which product should be displayed in the `SpecificProductView`.

```
public ViewModelBase CurrentProductViewModel
{
    get { return _currentProductViewModel; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _currentProductViewModel, value); }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in ProductListViewModel? If so, you you can bind DataContext of SpecificProductView  to CurrentProductViewModel in XAML.

Another approach would be using events. But I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer, I have tried to explain in my post (Edit 1) what doesn't work when I implement your solution.

Comment: Is OnProductNav defined in code-behind or ProductListViewModel?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand and the code you've posted doesn't show how you implement (relevant) views and view models. Just meaningless fragments. Anyway, your products should be displayed using a `ListBox`. You can then bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` (I assume it's of type `tblMATProduct `) to a property of your view model. This way you get the current `tblMATProduct` instance. Now, when this property changes you can execute your procedure and create the appropriate view models and assign them to properties. You bind this properties to the `DataContext` of your views.

Comment: Please post classes (reduced) and your views (reduced) to show the context and how you link them. This code fragments don't help at all to get a picture of the context. It must be clear for somebody who don't know you application to understand how your mentioned classes are working together. You are talking about view models and code-behind, but it's not obvious where your code fragments come from. It is impossible to help without information.

Comment: Yes, you are right @BionicCode. I have edited the original post to add more context!

Comment: @AdamŠtafa It is in the ProductListViewModel. I have just added it in the recent edit.

Comment: Thank you, this is much better. The question is, why don't you bind the `DataContext` of `SpecificProductView` to the `ProductListViewModel.CurrentProductViewModel` property? Is `SpecificProductView` a `Window`?

Comment: SpecificProductView is a UserControl. The problem here is that if it binds to it, it will just create a new instance of ProductListViewModel and it's CurrentProductViewModel will be equal to Null.

Comment: Who will create  a new instance of ProductListViewModel and why? How do you show the SpecificProductView?

Comment: Ok so the `MainWindowViewModel` creates the `ProductListViewModel` which will create the `SpecificProductViewModel` like this `SpecificProductVM = new SpecificProductViewModel(product);` Then, the problem is that the`SpecificProductView`will need to show info for that `specific product`. Therefore, the `DataContext `must be assigned to this instance because it has the product as an instance variable.

Comment: How and where is the `SpecificProductView` created?

Comment: @mm8 The `SpecificProductView` is created as soon as the `SpecificProductViewModel` is created because of the followingcommand in the `SpecificProductView.xaml` : `<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:SpecificProductViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>`

Comment: Setting the `DataContext` in the XAML markup is almost never a good idea and certainly not in this case when you want to set it to a specific instance of the view model. But you still haven't answered the question of *where and how" the `UserControl` is created.

Comment: @mm8, thanks for your tips. I have just edited the post (Edit 3) to answer your question in a more detailed fashion. I have never heard of explicitly instantiating the `UserControl` as you seem to be suggesting.  If it is possible, it would be really useful for me to know how to do so.

Comment: How is your `DataTemplate` applied? You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @mm8 you are right. By trying not to confuse the readers, I have neglected some important parts of the code. I have just edited the post (Edit 4) again to answer your question.

Comment: @RandyQuackers: Ok, then you should not explicitly set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` somewhere. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `ContentControl` that binds to the `CurrentProductViewModel` property that you set in your view model, you should simply remove the following part that sets the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to an new instance of the view model from your XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:SpecificProductViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The `UserControl` will then inherit the view model returned by the `CurrentProductViewModel` as its `DataContext`.

It is generally speaking a bad idea to explicitly set the `DataContext` property of a `UserControl`, either in XAML as well as in the code-behind, as this breaks the inheritance of the `DataContext` from the parent element.